# Amateur radio practice exam question

Tags: radio, test, ham-radio

The question is as follows:

> An interfering signal from a transmitter is found to have a frequency of 57 MHz (TV Channel 2 is 54 - 60 MHz). This signal could be the:

And the options are as follows:

```
A) crystal oscillator operating on its fundamental
B) second harmonic of a 10 metre transmission
C) seventh harmonic of an 80 metre transmission
D) third harmonic of a 15 metre transmission
```

Now in my mind options B and D are the same frequency as the second harmonic of a 10 meter transmission is 30 MHz*2=60 MHz and the third harmonic of a 15 meter transmission should be 20 MHz*3=60 MHz. I don’t see how one answer could be more correct than the other.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a general EE question, it might be better off at https://ham.stackexchange.com.

Comment: "harmonics" are sometimes counted differently; in some contexts (not really in this, but whatever, ham radio exam questions are full of incorrect and / or vague formulations in many countries of this earth), only the *odd* harmonics count; in some I could imagine you'd only count the even harmonics. I don't know – maybe this is one of these cases.

Comment: Also, let me do the quick math: $$ f=\frac c\lambda = \frac{3\cdot 10^8 \frac{\text m}{\text s}}{15\,\text m  }= 20\,\text{MHz,} $$ so no matter which harmonics you count, 57 MHz is not a multiple of 20 MHz and B and D are both *equally wrong*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller it’s in the range of 54-60 though and that 57 MHz transmission could quite possibly have a bandwidth of 6mhz assuming it utilized frequency modulation+ you have to assume the transmitters frequency control isn’t perfect

Comment: I fully agree this is a stupid question, but if your frequency control is not reliably with 3 MHz (capitalization is important, as M = mega = 1 million and m = milli = 1/1000) of 57 MHz, that's a frequency error of more than 5%: If your oscillator is that unreliable, no matter what you do with it, turn it of, and repair or replace it. No discussions: that is a broken oscillator.

Comment: About the possibility of it being a bandwidth rather than a tone: nope, none of the answer options include that option, so this must be about a single tone.

Comment: The 15 metre band is 21 - 21.45 MHz, so the third harmonic will be above 63 MHz - too high. 10 Metres is 28 - 29 MHz, so the second harmonic will be 56 - 58 MHz - looks like B is the right answer. (where did the 20 Hz and 30 Hz come from?)

Comment: @PeterBennett I didn’t take into account the band, I simply did 300meter=1mhz to solve for frequency but if you, write you comment as a solution I will Mark it as correct

Comment: Many people have posted mean comments for a legitimate question. Glad to see that one answer and one comment have provided a polite and valid answer. Need to mention that to answer correctly the above question you need to know the exact frequencies as the band name is approximating the frequencies

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 15 metre band is 21 - 21.45 MHz, so the third harmonic will be above 63 MHz - too high. 10 Metres is 28 - 29.7 MHz, so the second harmonic will be 56 - 59.4MHz - looks like B is the right answer.

You have to look at the defined band frequency limits, rather than the frequency calculated from the band name.

Comment: This is why this should be on the ham site!